# AWS Lambda : Connection timesout during connect with HBase

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hbase, aws-lambda

I have a set of AWS machines where Apache Hbase is setup.
I am accessing HBASE table through AWS-Lambda and getting Time-out error.
Its seems the function is able to access the machine but unable to do operation on HBase.
I checked the VPC setting(Subsets, Security group, inbound and outbound port) to Connect with Zookeeper machine but all are looking fine to me.

Can anyone suggest what happened:

```
public Void handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        Configuration hbaseConf = new Configuration();

        hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "XXX.XX.XX.XX");
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9000/hbase");
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.master", "XXX.XX.XX.XX:16000");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HTable hTable = null;
        try {
            hTable = new HTable(hbaseConf, "rulesoutput_abc");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(input)); 

        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("datareceived"),Bytes.toBytes("raju"));
        context.getLogger().log("put value: " + p);
        try {
            hTable.put(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.out.println("data inserted");

          // closing HTable
          try {
            hTable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```